# Have we ever seen an atom? If not, how do we know they exists?

Tags: atoms

Question is what exactly title says that have we ever seen an atom through any means (microscopes/equipments.etc)? If not, how do we know they exists?

Comment: Did you try Google? Imaging of atoms has been accomplished recently, and it's big news. There are really two questions here: 1) What do atoms look like? and 2) How did we know atoms existed before they could be imaged?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we make images of single atoms?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54431/)

Comment: Google STM (scanning tunneling microscope) or AFM (atomic force microscopy). And how do we know they exist... well the answer is physics...

Comment: Historically the combination of stoichiometry, the behavior of gasses as compared with the thermodynamics of the "ideal gas" and Einstein's explanation of Brownian motion taken together were considered sufficient proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Scanning tunneling microscopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope) can "see" atoms. Here is a 2008 issue of *Nature* magazine:

[image]

What you're really seeing here is an electrical equipotential surface, which is close enough to being a solid surface for most purposes. A scanning tunneling microscope (or the similar atomic force microscope) is like a very precise phonograph; it traces over a surface and senses the atomic-scale bumps in a surface. It's not too much inference to assume that the atomic-scale bumps are really atoms. The colors are added though; any atom is smaller than a wavelength of visible light.

How did we know atoms existed before that? Well, that's quite a story, and Wikipedia probably [tells it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom#History_of_atomic_theory) better than I can.