# Is it possible to view an atom?

Tags: optics, atoms, microscopy

Is it possible to view an atom?
What would it look like?

Would it resemble a traditional atomic diagram?

Comment: related: [Can we make images of single atoms?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54431/can-we-make-images-of-single-atoms?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to an article in PhysicsWorld on imaging a Hydrogen atom.http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/may/23/quantum-microscope-peers-into-the-hydrogen-atom